# CORS Preflight Keeps Failing

Tags: reactjs, iis, asp.net-web-api, axios, http-status-code-400

So my web app's Front-end is created using React.js and my back-end Web Api server is created using ASP .NET framework 4.7.2. With each request that I make to my back-end, I include the following custom headers (I use **Axios** to make the requests if that helps):

```js
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'UserId': `${UserId}`,
    'FE_URL': `${CurrentURL}`,
    'Authorization': `Basic ${ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
  }
})
```

Now both my front-end and back-end is hosted on IIS running on my PC. In my back-end I already added the following Response Headers:

[image]

Now correct me if I'm wrong, but my understanding is that with the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` being set to `*` should allow all response headers and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` being set to `*` should allow for the **OPTIONS** method to go through. Not sure what exactly I am doing wrong here.

Here is what the preflight request looks like:
[image: Pre-flight request]

Here is the headers to the actual request:
[image: ACtual request headers]

Comment: You can try to enable [failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules), it will provide the key error and warning.

Comment: You are not supposed to use HTTP Response Headers for CORS response headers. Please learn and use IIS CORS module, https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/getting-started-with-the-iis-cors-module

Comment: The preflight likely fails because the response has status code outside the 2xx range. Figure out why the status is 400 and fix that.